# CoreML Image Detection

Tags: swift, machine-learning, computer-vision, arkit, coreml

I want to implement an application, that is able to recognize pictures from camera input. I don't mean `classification` of objects, but rather detecting the exact single image from given set of images. So if I for example have an album with 500 pictures, then if I point a camera to one of them, then application will be able to tell it's filename. Most of tutorials I find about `CoreML` is strictly for image classification (recognizing class of object) and not about recognizing exact image name in camera. This needs to work from different angles as well, and all I can have for training the network is this album with many different pictures (single picture for single object). Can this be somehow achieved? I can't use `ARKit Image Tracking`, because there will be about 500 of these images, and I need to find at least a list of similar ones first with `CoreML` / `Vision`.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure, but I guess [perceptual hashing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Perceptual_hashing) might be able to help you. 
It works in a way that it makes some fingerprint from the reference images, and for a given image, it extracts the fingerprints as well, and then you can find the most similar fingerprints.

in this way, even if the new image is not 100% as the image in the dataset, you still can detect it.

It is actually not very hard to implement. but if you would like, i think [phash](https://www.phash.org/) library is a good one to use.